# Intent-filter: How to accept only "text/plain" intents containing the word "spaghetti"

Tags: android, android-intent, text, intentfilter

My app is about spaghetti, and it should allow you to share any `text/plain` content provided it's about spaghetti. So I need an intent-filter that accepts only such content.

In case it helps, these are example spaghetti:

[image: spaghetti]

Unfortunately, I only found a way to accept `text/plain` content, but I couldn't find anything [in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) to filter via the text itself.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Is this possible at all? Workarounds are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible at all?

No.

> Workarounds are welcome.

Accept all text, and if the text does not contain references to suitable pasta products, show an error and possibly `finish()` your activity to return the user to wherever they came from.

You could invent your own MIME type (e.g., `application/vnd.cprcrack.al.dente`), but since approximately zero other apps will be sharing things with that MIME type, the user will get hungry.